# referencing problem in void * pointer?

Tags: c++, c

This code:

```
int p = 10;
void *q;
*q = 10;
```

Does not compile:

> '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'void *'

However, this code compiles fine:

```
int p = 10;
void *q;
q = &p;
```

What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Error. What error? (In this case, it's a bit obvious, but you should always post the error.)

Comment: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'void *'

Comment: Your compiler is strange ... wht would it want to convert from `int` to `void*` given the statement `*q=10;`? ??? In that statement, the `10` has type `int` and the `*q` has type `void`.

Comment: In your first snippet, you are telling the compiler, "q is a pointer to some kind of data. I'm not telling you which type of data because I promise you won't need to know." You then tell the compiler, "convert 10 into whatever data type is at the location pointed to by q, and store it there." Since you didn't give it type information earlier, it can't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `void *` points to data of an unknown type (if it is initialized, which yours is not).

You can only assign to variables of a known type, or via pointers of a known type.

```
int p = 10;
void *q = &p;

*(int *)q = 20;

if (p != 20)
    ...something has gone horribly wrong...
```

This converts the `void *` into an `int *` and then assigns a value to that dereferenced integer pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Any pointer can be converted to `void*`, but it is illegal to dereference a pointer to `void`.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet is *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

The two pieces of code (try to) do different things.

The first one is trying to assign the value 10 to the object `q` points to. There are two problems here. First you never initialized the pointer. You need to have it point somewhere before you can change the value of what it points to. And second, you cannot dereference `void*` because the type is not known.

The second piece of code is assigning the address of the variable `p` to `q`. After this `q` will point to the object that is stored in `p`.

Answer (score 1):

This changes the address in memory `q` points to:

```
q = &p;
```

This cannot figure out the type of what `q` points to (`int`, `long`, `std::string`, `int**`, etc); all it knows is the location in memory:

```
*q = 10;
```

You could do:

```
int *iq = static_cast<int*>(q);
*iq = 10;
```

You may want to read more about [`void*`s](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dereference a void pointer. And even if you could, your code would be writing to some random memory address and probably crash.

In the second code block you are assigning the address of the pointer which works fine since you can assign any memory address to a `void*`